# Unified Process (UP) versus Unified Modeling Language(UML)

Tags: modeling, uml, methodology, specifications

What is the difference between Unified Process (UP) and Unified Modeling Language (UML)? Is there a difference, or is using either one the same?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In very simple words:

UML is a modelling language, a set of rules and standards for drawing digrams. 
UP is a software development methodology or process, tells you step by step what you should do to develop software! Some of those steps may require drawing UML diagrams.